# Iterable object: Reduce to a single value

Tags: c#, aggregate, reduce, accumulate

Is there a way to reduce an iterable object to a single value? In javascript this can be done like so:

```js
var array = [{num: 1}, {num: 10}, {num: 5}];

var result = array.reduce((cur, val) => val.num > cur ? val.num : cur, 0);
    
console.log(result);
```

The above will return the largest number in the array of objects.

Currently in `C#` I am using a `foreach` to find the largest item, but is there a built in function similar to the javascript `reduce` method from above?

Comment: `array.Aggregate(0, (cur, val) => val.num > cur ? val.num : cur);`

Comment: @Aominè But what if the list is all negative numbers?

Comment: @JonathonChase what do you mean? the OP is calling `reduce` on a list of objects.

Comment: @Aominè Sure, but if you seed the reduce with 0, and all the objects' num properties are < 0, then 0 will be returned despite not being a member of the list.

Comment: @JonathonChase that's what the OPs code is doing, so I just replicated their javascript code into C# but yes using `Int32.MinValue` as the identity value like you've done would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of reduce in LINQ is [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);

var max = nums.Aggregate(Int32.MinValue, (acc,elem) => acc < elem ? elem : acc);
```

Comment: Aggregate only takes one argument in 3.1, so you can't chose the result value type

Comment: @robertotomás Are you sure about this? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Aggregate__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____1_System_Func___1___0___1__System_Func___1___2__) looks to be the same seeded overload.

Comment: I'm sorry, this may be specific to a raw array like MyObjects[] .. I have a Dictionary<string, MyObjects[]> and calling dict.Values.Aggregate gives me the error I had mentioned.

Comment: @robertotomás Values is a list of lists in that case. You may need to flatten it with `SelectMany(x => x)` before you aggregate.